# Honda Civic- no start-no crank

Tags: honda, starting, civic, ignition

I have a 1989 Honda Civic DX Hatchback.  I tried to start the vehicle after running it for some time.  It did not start.  When I turn the ignition switch, the battery light comes on (normal) and brake light comes on (normal) and the check engine light comes on momentarily and then goes out.  There is no start and no crank.  I checked the operation of the solenoid and starter by - bypassing the ignition circuit - and the car starts and runs normally.  I checked the ignition switch in accordance with the shop manual and it is operating properly. I checked the starter relay and the clutch interlock relay (it is a manual transmission) and they are operating normally.  I do not have any indication on the ECU with the exception of one momentarily blip when turning the ignition switch to the starting position. I checked the wiring for the starting circuit and found no problems.  I am looking for ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Double check everything. If you can power the S terminal on the starter and get the car to start than it's on the other side of the circuit.

Pull the relay again and make sure when someone presses the clutch the relay coil is grounded.

Check your fuses, the relay should have power on two pins, one that powers the relay coil while cranking and one that passes power to the starter S terminal when the relay closes.

Check for ground on the pin that goes from the relay to the S terminal on the starter. If you don't have ground on the pin there is issue with the wiring.